# Problem with init genesis.json

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis

I created my genesis.json, then init it into 2 different paths. But these 2 path didn't contain same genesis file.

How to make these 2 use same genesis file? Or How an I wrong?

This is my genesis.json

```
{
"config": {
        "chainId": 10701,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },

  "alloc"      : {
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {"balance": "2000"},
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {"balance": "5000"}
    },

  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x00100",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000002378",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

Command for first path.

```
geth --datadir "E:\blockchain\database\node a" --networkid 10701 --nodiscover --nat none -identity node1 init C:\Users\ZephyR\Desktop\genesis.json

geth --datadir "E:\blockchain\database\node a" --networkid 10701 --nodiscover --nat none -identity node1 --rpc --rpcapi "web3, etc, personal" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

[image]

Command for second path.

```
geth --datadir "E:\blockchain\database\node b" --networkid 10701 --nodiscover --nat none -identity node2 init C:\Users\ZephyR\Desktop\genesis.json

geth --datadir "E:\blockchain\database\node b" --networkid 10701 --nodiscover --nat none --datadir node2 --rpc --rpcapi "web3, etc, personal" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport 2222 --port 30302 --ipcpath node/geth.ipc console
```

[image]

However, It's work on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the command you are using to start the second node. It specifies datadir twice: `--datadir "E:\blockchain\database\node b"` and `--datadir node2`. Therefore the second datadir (node2) is used which is not the one that you initialised with your genesis.json.

You might also want to check your `-identity` parameter - that should have two dashes: `--identity`.

Finally - how are you planning on making the nodes communicate with each other? One option is to use `admin.addPeer(<address of other node>)` from the second node's console. The other is to supply this address to `--bootnodes` when launching the second geth node.